# All export options are available. Not sure how to integrate it

Tags: jquery

I have created the below html file which is perfectly working fine and showing export options without any issues along with the data.

```
    <html>
  <head>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css">

  </head>
  <body>

        <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
    </script>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>




  </body>


</html>
```

Also uploaded the html file in the following free servers as well. Download if required

https://ufile.io/amnmz

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06400901257534134951

However i would like to provide few additional export options such as word, png, jpeg, json etc.,

When i searched the internet i come across the link - http://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/ but not sure how to bring those options in the html file

Please kindly help me with the updated html file which includes the above options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://technoscripts.com/export-html-table/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Export HTML table to Excel / CSV / PDF / JSON / PNG / WORD / XML / TXT using jQuery</title><meta name="description" content="DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery JavaScript library."> 
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- export plug-in files start-->
<!-- <script src="libs/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/tableExport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- export plug-in files end-->
<!-- Toggle Button code start-->
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#exportButton").click(function () {
$("#exportTable").toggle();
});
});
</script>
<!-- Toggle Button code end-->
</head>  
<body style="margin:20px auto">  
<div class="container">
<div class="row header" style="text-align:center;color:green">
<h3>Export HTML table to Excel / Word / PDF / JSON / PNG / XML / CSV / TXT / SQL</h3>
<button data-toggle="exportTable" id="exportButton" class="btn btn-primary">click here to Export Data</button><br/><br/>
<div id="exportTable" style="display:none;">
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'json', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/json.png' width="24"/> JSON</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'json', escape: 'false', ignoreColumn: '[2,3]'});"><img src='images/json.png' width="24"/> JSON (ignoreColumn)</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'json', escape: 'true'});"><img src='images/json.png' width="24"/> JSON (with Escape)</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'xml', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/xml.png' width="24"/> XML</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'sql'});"><img src='images/sql.png' width="24"/> SQL</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'csv', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/csv.png' width="24"/> CSV</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'txt', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/txt.png' width="24"/> TXT</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'excel', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/xls.png' width="24"/> XLS</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'doc', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/word.png' width="24"/> Word</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'powerpoint', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/ppt.png' width="24"/> PowerPoint</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'png', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/png.png' width="24"/> PNG</a>
<a href="#" onClick ="$('#myTable').tableExport({type: 'pdf', escape: 'false'});"><img src='images/pdf.png' width="24"/> PDF</a>
</div><br/>
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">  
<thead>  
<tr>  
<th>Sr.No</th>  
<th>Name</th>  
<th>Country</th>  
<th>Salary</th>  
</tr>  
</thead>  
<tbody>  
<tr>  
<td>001</td>  
<td>Rahul</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>20000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>002</td>  
<td>Charles</td>  
<td>United Kingdom</td>  
<td>28000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>003</td>  
<td>Menshril</td>  
<td>Australia</td>  
<td>70000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>004</td>  
<td>Ganesh</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>18000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>005</td>  
<td>Maithili</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>12000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>006</td>  
<td>Pavan</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>50000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>007</td>  
<td>Rakesh</td>  
<td>US</td>  
<td>75000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>008</td>  
<td>Mayur</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>100000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>009</td>  
<td>NiRRaNjan</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>85000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>010</td>  
<td>Tanmay</td>  
<td>Austria</td>  
<td>30000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>011</td>  
<td>Sara</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>750000</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td>012</td>  
<td>JonRoot</td>  
<td>India</td>  
<td>65000</td>  
</tr>  
</tbody>  
</table>
</div>
</body>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myTable').dataTable();
});
</script>
</html>
```